# How often does play store invoke android download manager?

Tags: android, google-play-services

Google Play Store uses GCM(Google Cloud Messaging) to receive app update notifications.

Once the play store knows that update is available and automatic updates are set on by the user, then it will try to download the update.

If due to some reason(no internet connectivity or any other reason) if update download fails, then when will play store again invoke the android download manager???

Is there a fixed interval after which play store will invoke the android download manager?

***Note : I am working on a HTTP proxy which is required to deny all the app update requests during a particular interval. So i want to make sure this process of update download is repeated again after some time so that user gets updated.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a fixed interval after which play store will invoke the android download manager?

The policies that the Play Store uses for dealing with retries is up to the Play Store implementation. This is proprietary and subject to change.

> I am working on a HTTP proxy which is required to deny all the app update requests during a particular interval

You have no means of ensuring that any given app (written by Google or otherwise) will use your proxy (assuming anyone is willing to install the proxy in the first place).

Comment: OK, so it depends upon the implementation. But can I assume that the policy will retry again within a day? Is there any Upper limit on this retry period?

Comment: @MohitSingh: "But can I assume that the policy will retry again within a day? Is there any Upper limit on this retry period?" -- the only people who can answer this question work for Google. Perhaps if you got a job at Google, you could get at their internal documentation on this. Otherwise, there is no official documentation, and therefore you should not be assuming anything.